# Outer div grid position affects inner div grid position

Tags: html, css

When I run this, I get that the text for inner-div is placed based off of the outer-div's grid positioning. Isn't the position supposed to cascade as part of CSS? These also aren't my real id's and classes (yeah the naming stinks I know).

```css
#outer-outer {
    text-align: center;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 5vw 45vw 45vw 5vw;
    grid-template-rows: 30vh 29vh 29vh 29vh 29vh 29vh;
    grid-template-areas: ". header header ." ". main main ." ". main main ." ". main main ." ". main main ." ". main main .";
    justify-items: center;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}

#quote{
    font-weight: bold;
    grid-column-start: 2;
    grid-column-end: 4;
    grid-row-start: 1;
    grid-row-end: 2;
    white-space: pre-line;
}


#what-is-ll{
    font-size: x-large;
    font-weight: lighter;
    grid-column-start: 3;
    grid-column-end: 4;
    grid-row-start: 2;
    grid-row-end: 3;
}
#outer-div{
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 2;
    grid-row-start: 2;
    grid-row-end: 3;
}
#inner-div{
    grid-column-start: 2;
    grid-column-end: 3;
    grid-row-start: 3;
    grid-row-end: 4;
}
```

```html
<div id ="outer-outer">

    <h1 id = "quote">
        Lorem Ipsum
    </h1>

    <div id="what-is-ll">
        <h2 id="what-is-ll-title">

        </h2>
        <div id="what-is-ll-body">
            <p>
                Lorem Ipsum
            </p>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div id="outer-div">
        <h2 id="inner-div">
            Why make this?
        </h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried moving the column numbers around for inner-div to no avail but changing the column and row numbers of outer-div worked perfectly. [This is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zm9CN.png) "Why make this" is supposed to be where inner-div defines it to be.

EDIT: Ok I think I understand why this happens after coming back to it. The `outer-div` acts like a container, so the `inner-div` can't leave that.

**My issue now is that let's say I want to have `outer-div` hold multiple `inner-div`'s. If I want to keep these `inner-div`'s in alternating columns i.e. 2 then 3 then 2..., and I change the `grid-column-end` of `outer-div` to 4, the inner divs are stretched across the 2nd and 3rd columns. These columns are described in the linked image.** The "Why Make This" is supposed to be in either the 2nd or 3rd column.

I want the page to look like the flexbox's [here](https://www.yellowleafhammocks.com/pages/about-us)

Comment: there is no way that the (portion of) code you shared gives the result of the image so please share the full code

Comment: I believe it's fully there now @TemaniAfif

Answer (score 0):

Since the `div` with id `#outer-outer` is divided like `grid-template-columns: 5vw 45vw 45vw 5vw;`,hence for `div` with id `outer-div` You need to start from the second column and end at third column:

```css
#outer-outer {
    text-align: center;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 5vw 45vw 45vw 5vw;
    grid-template-rows: 30vh 29vh 29vh 29vh 29vh 29vh;
    grid-template-areas: ". header header ." ". main main ." ". main main ." ". main main ." ". main main ." ". main main .";
    justify-items: center;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}

#quote{
    font-weight: bold;
    grid-column-start: 2;
    grid-column-end: 4;
    grid-row-start: 1;
    grid-row-end: 2;
    white-space: pre-line;
}


#what-is-ll{
    font-size: x-large;
    font-weight: lighter;
    grid-column-start: 3;
    grid-column-end: 4;
    grid-row-start: 2;
    grid-row-end: 3;
}
#outer-div{
    grid-column-start: 2; /* start from 2*/
    grid-column-end: 3;/* end at 2*/
    grid-row-start: 2;
    grid-row-end: 3;
}
#inner-div{
    grid-column-start: 2;
    grid-column-end: 3;
    grid-row-start: 3;
    grid-row-end: 4;
}
```

```html
<div id ="outer-outer">
    <h1 id = "quote">
        Lorem Ipsum
    </h1>
    <div id="what-is-ll">
        <h2 id="what-is-ll-title">

        </h2>
        <div id="what-is-ll-body">
            <p>
                Lorem Ipsum
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="outer-div">
        <h2 id="inner-div">
            Why make this?
        </h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've actually just thought of why this works and I've edited accordingly! Can you please clarify on what I've just said?

Comment: Sorry I couldn't understand, but based on the website you mentioned, do you just wanna show some texts on one side and a relevant picture on another side? If yes, then why don't you use flex boxing?

Comment: I think that's my plan now. It seems like the best option.

Comment: Good luck with flexbox